# Keep only red channel of an image using GDI()

Tags: windows, image, winapi, bitmap, gdi

I initially had a color image which i made it grayscale by copying only red channels i.e, first 8 bits of RGB(24bit). This was done as some processing required the image to be grayscale.After the processing i have to display this image on screen using GDI. So i have to copy put the gray values into red chanel of the final output. Something like setpixel(i,j,RGB(grayvalue,0,0)). How do i achieve this using GDI?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by David, its been solved with solution mentioned in the following thread 
[display red channel of image using GDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052165/display-red-channel-of-image-using-gdi/23054624?noredirect=1#comment35227995_23054624)