# display red channel of image using GDI

Tags: windows, image, winapi, bitmap, gdi

I have 24 bit RGB image.I want to display only the red channel onto the display using GDI. Should i use palette for that? What is the strategy to be used?

Please guide me appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way is to use `BitBlt`. Create another 24 bit bitmap of the same size as your RGB image. Fill it with pure red. Then use `BitBlt` with `SRCAND`. As described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370.aspx) this

> Combines the colors of the source and destination rectangles by using the Boolean AND operator.

Comment: With this only the values present in r channel of my RGB wil be copied in the destination rectangle right?

Comment: Thanks David! Can u also help with another issue present in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051008/keep-only-red-channel-of-an-image-using-gdi?rq=1

Comment: That's exactly the same question as this one, as I read it. The exact same answer. There you are asking for a new image that consists solely of the red channel of the original image

Comment: but since the original image is a grayscale image now will BitBlt combine(and operation) that with corresponding gray value and put that gray value to red channel of destination?

Comment: In GDI, even grayscale images are implicitly converted to RGB and Shown on screen?

Comment: @user3462791 Typically a gray scale image is an RGB image. In fact all windows bitmaps express colors using RGB. It is only gray scale by dint of having the same value in all three channels. Once you zeroise out the blue and green channels it is pure red.

Comment: Thanx a tonne for That :)